# Matlab datenum confuses between buddhist year and christian year

Tags: matlab, datetime

When run these two commands in Matlab command line:

```
dateNumber = datenum('20130101', 'yyyymmdd');
dateString = datestr(dateNumber, 'yyyymmdd')
```

I got

```
dateString = 14700101
```

I suspect that it is a confusion between Buddhist year and Christian year because `2013-1470 == 543` (Buddhist year started in counting 543 years before Christian year). In other words, the `datenum` function interpreted `2013` as Buddhist year and convert it to a date number representing Christian year, `1470`, but `datestr` function did not convert it back to Buddhsit year.

How can I configure the `datenum` function so that it understands `2013` as a Christian year?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your output. I got dateString = 20130101

Comment: Yes, I tested it on my friend's computer and also got `dateString = 20130101`. I don't know why the problem occurred in my machine.

Comment: what do you get if you type datestr(now, 'yyyymmdd')

Comment: I got `ans = 20140215`

Comment: FIY, I live in Bangkok, Thailand, GMT+7.

Comment: In datenum document, it says, A serial date number of 1 corresponds to Jan-1-0000. The year 0000 is merely a reference point and is not intended to be interpreted as a real year. So datenum('00000101', 'yyyymmdd') is supposed to return 1, and datenum('20130101', 'yyyymmdd')=735235

Comment: In my machine, `datenum('20130101', 'yyyymmdd')=536908`. I think for now I will check if `datenum('20130101', 'yyyymmdd')=536908`, I will add `735235-536908=198327` to it. Thank you very much.

Comment: What does matlab return, if you run `class(java.util.Calendar.getInstance())`?

Comment: @Daniel, it returned `ans = sun.util.BuddhistCalendar`.

Comment: @asinkxcoswt: Your OS-Default seems to be set to `BuddhistCalendar`. Is this intended?

Comment: I didn't know about it. I set the location to Thailand when installing Windows 8 a week ago. Does this affect the Calendar?

Comment: @Danial, I have changed my system format and locale to English and the problem is solved. Thank you very much.

Comment: That's awesome. This is worth reporting as a bug to MathWorks, since their date functions are not documented as being sensitive to locale Calendar settings and the `datenum`/`datestr` asymmetry is definitely a surprise.

Comment: Indeed seems worthy of a bug report. @Daniel I suppose you lead to the answer so I hereby encourage you to post it below and make sure this question won't remain open.